# MySQL FIND_IN_SET not returning data for middle elements

Tags: mysql

I have some data and I thought that FIND_IN_SET was working for me but apparently it was because what I Was looking for was the first element.

I.e.

```
SELECT * FROM myData WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, field)>0
```

returns nothing when the data is as follows

```
|----field----| |---- Title ----|
|1, 2, 3, 4   | | Something her |
|0, 2, 3, 4   | | Something her |
|12, 2, 3, 4  | | Something her |
|133, 2, 3, 4 | | Something her |
```

It doesn't recognize the 2 in the field - is there a problem with my query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separation character is a `,`, it means that all elements except of first have a leading space.

In your case `2` is not found because there is no such element there, but `' 2'` (`2` with a leading space)

PS: you generally must use a one-to-many or many-to-many implementation instead of what you have at the moment.

Comment: Ah perfect thank you - could you elaborate on what you mean by one-to-many or many-to-many? That table isn't a real table by the way, it was just to explain the problem.